# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.events.Model.IMG

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

here is my activity code:-

```
class event_images : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var imageAdapter: Imageadapter? = null
    private var img1: MutableList<IMG>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_images)

        recyclerView = event_images
        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(baseContext)

        img1 = ArrayList()
        imageAdapter = baseContext?.let { Imageadapter(it, img1 as ArrayList<IMG>, true) }
        recyclerView?.adapter = imageAdapter

        val wimagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events")
        e_imagesRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children){
                    val image = snapshot.getValue(IMG::class.java)
                    if (image != null){
                        event_images.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        (img1 as ArrayList<IMG>)?.add(image)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })


    }
}
```

here is adapter code:-

```
class Imageadapter (private var mContext: Context,
                    private var mimages: List<IMG>,
                    private var isActivity: Boolean = false) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Imageadapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Imageadapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.images_adapter, parent, false)
        return Imageadapter.ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Imageadapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val imageid = mimages[position]

        Picasso.get().load(imageid.getImageUrl()).into(holder.ImageIv)
        holder.Datetv.text = imageid.getDate()
        holder.Venuetv.text = imageid.getVenue()

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mimages.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var ImageIv: ImageView = itemView.image_ret
        var Datetv: TextView = itemView.date_ret
        var Venuetv: TextView = itemView.venue_ret

    }
```

here is my model code:-

```
class IMG {
    private var ImageUrl: ImageView = ""
    private var date: String = ""
    private var venue: String = ""

    constructor()

    constructor(ImageUrl: ImageView,
                date: String,
                venue: String){
        this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl
        this.date= date
        this.venue = venue
    }



    fun getDate(): String
    {
        return date
    }

    fun setDate(Date: String){
        this.date = Date
    }

    fun getImageUrl(): String {
        return ImageUrl
    }
    fun setImageUrl(ImageUrl: String){
        this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl
    }

    fun getVenue(): String
    {
        return venue
    }
    fun setVenue(Venue: String){
        this.venue = Venue
    }
}
```

The error my project is:-

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.events.Model.IMG at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436) at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232) at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80) at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203) at com.example.events.event_images$onCreate$2.onDataChange(event_images.kt:38) at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75) at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63) at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

the snapshot of the db is:-

[image: database snapshot]

I don't know how solve this error.
Can someone help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the database encountered a single string property, where your code said it should expect an entire `IMG` object in your `snapshot.getValue(IMG::class.java)` call.

It's impossible for us to say for sure why this is, but check the `events` node in your database, because at least one child node/property under it is a string value, instead of an `IMG` object.

---

**Update after you added the screenshot of your database**:

Your `events` node contains the properties for a single event. So when you loop over `dataSnapshot.children`, the `snapshot` variable will first point to the `date` property, then to the `imageurl` property, then to the `venue` property. None of these properties is a valid `IMG` object on their own, which is why the SDK throws an exception.

The best solution is to change your database to have/allow multiple events under the `events` node:

```
events: {
  "-Mfdskheuheas...": {
    date: "...",
    imageurl: "..."
    venue: "..."
  },
  "-Mzsdfhkerqas...": {
    date: "...",
    imageurl: "..."
    venue: "..."
  },
}
```

You'd typically call `push()` in your code to generate that extra level in the database, which generates keys of the type `-M...` above. Also see the documentation on [adding items to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Alternative if you really only want to have the properties of a single event under `/events`, you can remove the loop from your `onDataChange`:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    val image = dataSnapshot.getValue(IMG::class.java)
    if (image != null){
        event_images.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        (img1 as ArrayList<IMG>)?.add(image)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added db snapshot. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank. It worked out for me. Now I just have one problem. When I enter for the first time in the activity, it didn't show anything. After going back if I again enter same activity it show me the data.

Comment: Every time you change the data set that the view is support to show (so when you add an image to the array list in your case), you have to call `imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. You solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change, If issue isn't resolved. Then please share your DB snapshot.

```
class IMG {
    private var ImageUrl: ImageView = ""
```

AND

```
constructor(ImageUrl: ImageView,
                date: String,
                venue: String){
        this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl
        this.date= date
        this.venue = venue
    }
```

to

```
class IMG {
    private var ImageUrl: String = ""
```

AND

```
constructor(ImageUrl: String,
            date: String,
            venue: String){
    this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl
    this.date= date
    this.venue = venue
}
```

Comment: it didn't work out. I have added snapshot of database.